# Meteor JS Can't call non-function: undefined Error

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a problem with this particular error with my MeteorJS application. The most interesting part is that this error occurs only on my production server. When checking localhost everything is correct, without any errors:

Here you have the error:

```
Error: Can't call non-function: undefined
    at f.call (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:115)
    at f.mustacheImpl (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:115)
    at Object.f.mustache (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:115)
    at HTML.LI.HTML.DIV.HTML.DIV.HTML.DIV.HTML.IMG.src (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:314)
    at Object.c._withCurrentView (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:63)
    at c._HTMLJSExpander.def.visitAttribute (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:63)
    at i.TransformingVisitor.def.visitAttributes (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:57)
    at c._HTMLJSExpander.def.visitAttributes (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:63)
    at Object.c._expandAttributes (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:63)
    at f (94f45a0d5ba7150d1744831d8acd9020a2ddee9c.js:63)
```

Now it's hard for me to have any assumptions about why is this error appearing. To tell the truth for past few hours I tried to solve this bug without any kind of success.

Probably error is caused by some part of code seen below, but I don't know which part yet:

```
setRecentHandsPagination = (data, sort) =>
  RecentHandsPagination.set
    filters: setFiltersForRecentHandsPagination(data)
    sort: setSortForRecentHandsPagination(sort)

setFiltersForRecentHandsPagination = (data) =>
  newFilters = new RecentHandsFilters(data).setFilters()

  Session.setPersistent 'recentHandsFilters', newFilters
  newFilters

setSortForRecentHandsPagination = (sort) =>
  newSort = if sort? then else {createdAt: 1}

  Session.setPersistent 'recentHandsSort', newSort
  newSort

AutoForm.hooks
  handsFilters:
    onSubmit: (data) ->
      @event.preventDefault()

      emptyFilters = []
      for filterName in PokerFiltersNames
        unless data[filterName]?
          emptyFilters.push filterName
          $("#handsFilters [data-schema-key='#{filterName}'] input[type='checkbox']")
            .prop 'checked', true
          $("#handsFilters [data-schema-key='#{filterName}'] option[value='#{Pocademy.AddedDate.THIS_MONTH}']")
            .prop 'selected', true

      if emptyFilters.length > 0
        defaultFilters = RecentHandsFilters.defaultAttrs()

      for filterName in emptyFilters
        data[filterName] = defaultFilters[filterName]

      setRecentHandsPagination(data)

      $('#dropdown-recent-hands.open').removeClass('open')
      @done()

Template.recentHandsFilters.helpers
  handsFiltersDefaultDoc: ->
    defaultFilters = RecentHandsFilters.defaultAttrs()

    filters =
      pokerGames: defaultFilters.pokerGames
      pokerTypes: defaultFilters.pokerTypes
      pokerVariants: defaultFilters.pokerVariants
      pokerTables: defaultFilters.pokerTables
      pokerCreatedAt: defaultFilters.pokerCreatedAt

Template.recentHandsFilters.events
  'click #showAllHandsBtn': (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation()
    AutoForm.resetForm 'handsFilters'

    setRecentHandsPagination()

    $('#dropdown-recent-hands.open').removeClass('open')

  'click #addHand': (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation()
    AutoForm.resetForm 'handsFilters'

  'click .cancel-dropdown': (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation()
    $('#dropdown-recent-hands.open').removeClass('open')

Template.recentHandsFilters.onDestroyed ->
  RecentHandsPagination.unsubscribe()

Template.recentHandsFilters.onCreated ->
  setRecentHandsPagination()
```

Comment: Post the templates as well, particularly any template with something like `<img src="{{someHelper}}">`

Comment: Have you solved this plz ? I'm getting the same error. Thank you.